# How to use "Or" statement in MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am facing problem while Querying the following in MongoDB C#. My code in mongo client is

```
db.collection.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ,{price:100},{name:"x"}] } )
```

but how to query the same in C#.
I was able to query the following mongo client code statement

```
db.collection.find({type:"food"},{name:1,quantity:1})
```

as

```
var match = new BsonDocument() { { "$match", new BsonDocument { {"type":"food" } } } };
var project = new BsonDocument(){ { "$project", new BsonDocument{ { "name", 1 } { "quantity", 1 } } } };
AggregateArgs AggregationPipeline = new AggregateArgs() { Pipeline = new[] { match, project } };
var aggregate = Collection.Aggregate(AggregationPipeline);
```

I am using Mongo C Sharp Driver 1.9.2.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First, add a builder:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
```

Then a filter like this:

```
var filter = builder.Lt("quantity", 20) | builder.Eq("price", 10) | other stuff)
```

And finally something like:

```
db.collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @Mahdi , I am using MongoCSharpDriver.1.9.2.  Builders context does not exist in this version. Thanks