# mongodb c# client problem with $or query with the same operator

Tags: c#, mongodb

In MongoDb Compass I can query a collection like the following:
`{ age: { $eq: "65", $eq: 65}  }`

As you might ask - I don't know if age is a string or number.
How can I make such a query in c#?
I tried a IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> and give this to a BsonDocument - but I get an error with duplicate keys which is obvious cause there are two $eq operators.
But how to do it right in c#?

```
var para = comparisonOperator.Parameter.Name;
var op = FilterComparisonOperators.GetComparisonMongoDbOperator(comparisonOperator.Name);
var value = comparisonOperator.Value.Name;
if (int.TryParse(value, out int intValue))
{
    var bsonDocument = new BsonDocument(op, intValue);
    filterDocument.AddRange(new BsonDocument(para, bsonDocument));
    filterDocument.AddRange(new BsonDocument(para, bsonDocument));
}
else
{
    var bsonDocument = new BsonDocument(op, value);
    filterDocument.AddRange(new BsonDocument(para, bsonDocument));
}
```

I want to query a number like 65 as number or string.

Comment: I think compass/JavaScript may just be hiding the same error that you are getting there as well.  In any case, `$in` is probably what you want

Comment: @user20042973 that's a good point, but I want queries like $gte or $lt too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$or` like [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AoPw9odn8Fi) or `$in` like [this other query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xkfKvM7N5PL) so you can try something like this in Linq way:

Using `$or` (`||`)

```cs
var result = collection
               .AsQueryable<YourClass>()
               .Where(x => x.Age == 65 || x.Age == "65")
               .ToList();
```

Using `$in` (`.In()`)

```cs
var result = collection
               .AsQueryable<YourClass>()
               .Where(x => x.age.In(new[] { 65, "65" }))
               .ToList();
```

Or something like this (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39573756/13464279))

Using `$or`:

```cs
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("age", 65) | builder.Eq("age", "65");
db.collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Using `$in`:

```cs
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.In("age", new object[] { 65, "65" });
db.collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: is it possible to get the BsonDocument from the FilterBuilder? Like { age: { $eq: "65", $eq: 65}  }  .ToBsonDocument() is looking a bit wierd.